# How do I slice a large image using GIMP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, images, gimp

How can I edit a large image file on Linux?

I have a high-res scan of an image, and I'd like to select parts of it and save them individually to be able to manipulate them.

I used GIMP to place markers on the image, and then tried using *Web → Slice* to autoslice the image, but it comes up with an error after a while and it only saves the first image.

edit: The image is 10208x14032 pixels, 140Mb in size. The testing computer has 3Gb of RAM

Answer (score 4):

I am all about using GIMP for everything and love it. However let me suggest [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this task.  I have a file called kids.png that is 2149x1433. I use the following command found at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile and end up with 6 images that are identified as follows

Command

```
convert kids.png  +gravity -crop 1000x1000  tiles_%d.png
```

Results

tiles_0.png PNG 1000x1000 2149x1433+0+0
tiles_1.png PNG 1000x1000 2149x1433+1000+0
tiles_2.png PNG 149x1000 2149x1433+2000+0
tiles_3.png PNG 1000x433 2149x1433+0+1000
tiles_4.png PNG 1000x433 2149x1433+1000+1000
tiles_5.png PNG 149x433 2149x1433+2000+1000

Then I put them back together with

```
convert tiles_[0-5].png -mosaic new.png
```